# How to search at the beginning of a title field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I want to find products in elastic of a certain name & color and brand. To do this, specify 3 fields for the search. Elastic returns products that I have not searched for.
Input query can be any, for example, I decided to find blenders in black color of a certain brand but the query can include anything.

```
POST products/_search 
{
  "_source": [ "Title","Brand", "SKU", "Color"  ], //which field do I want to get in result json
    "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query" : "blender hendi black",   // input query
            "fields": ["Brand","Title", "Color"],  //search fields
            "minimum_should_match": "2", // I also tried query without this attribute
            "fuzziness": 1      //misspelling // I also tried query without this attribute
        }
    },
    "size": 10
}
```

```
Elastic result:
There are only two objects in this example, but the whole response contains many products that are not relevant like the second product in the example  - "Replacement die for  Hendi sealing machine made of polished aluminum Black silicone gasket"

{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 10.110109,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "products",
        "_id": "2ymTUYcBoby_8DNrw9q0",
        "_score": 10.110109,
        "_ignored": [
          "event.original.keyword",
          "Long_description.keyword"
        ],
        "_source": {
          "Brand": "saro",
          "Title": "Cup blender black 2 L, 0.95 kW",
          "Color": "Black",
          "SKU": "329-20151"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "products",
        "_id": "sCmSUYcBoby_8DNr4WZp",
        "_score": 9.749819,
        "_ignored": [
          "event.original.keyword"
        ],
        "_source": {
          "Brand": "hendi",
          "Title": "Replacement die for  Hendi sealing machine made of polished aluminum Black silicone gasket",
          "Color": "Silver",
          "SKU": "HEN-805589"
        }
      }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I understand why elastic finds products that are not blenders, because in the title occurs the name of the color and the product brand name, which turns out to be a match for the two words from the query. How this case can be solved? How to make elastic return only what I expect?

```
I did not change anything in the mapping it created itself

{
  "products": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "Color": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "Brand": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "Title": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
```

I didn't change the standard mapping. I keep all products in the same index. Although I have quite different products with a different number of fields, is it ok to store different entities in the same index? I couldn't find a specific answer...
Thank you in advance if you follow me in the right way!

Comment: This is classic recall vs precision. I believe that you could improve the results if the products most related to the input term were at the top of the results list. What I say is for you to use match queries on each field individually in combination with your multi-match.
Another tip is to use filters to allow users to narrow down the results.

Comment: Even if you have a lot of results the relevant ones should be at the top. In addition to the results, you can provide a list of filters (think of Facets) at this point, you can have the filters by brand and color and with that the user would be easier to find products with the desired color and brand.